# How to implement Precision Time Protocol (PTP) on Rpi3 p2p network?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, timekeeping

I was just wondering whether IEEE 1588 PTP can be implemented on RPi-3 network? Like any other linux system whether ptp4l and phc2sys are functional in raspbian?

Any idea, link or suggestion? Any helping hand, please?

Answer (score 3):

There are some kernel driver modifications that must be made, however, someone has already done that work and shared their work here:
https://github.com/twteamware/raspberrypi-ptp